# How to create my specific error message for model property in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have my Model :

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
      include ActiveUUID::UUID
       validates :location, :description, presence: true
end
```

and DB model :

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :courses, :id => false do |t|
      t.uuid :id, :primary_key => true, :null => false
      t.datetime :date_start, :null => false
      t.float :price, :null => false
      t.datetime :date_end
      t.text :description
      t.text :location, :null => false
      t.uuid :mentor_uuid
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and my method in controller which i cal via ajax :

```
  def create
     @course  = Course.new(params.require(:course).permit(:description, :location))
    if @course.save
     render json: @course, status: 200
    else
       render json: @course.errors.full_messages, status: 400
    end 
  end
```

and here is my ajax call :

```
var course = {"description" : "Timo", 'location' : 'hahahah'};
    $scope.test = function(){
        $http.post('api/courses.json', course).success( function (data) {
        }).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data){

            console.log(data);
        });
  };
```

So this return me an error with : `["Date end can't be blank", "Date start can't be blank", "Price can't be blank"]`, but what if i want to change error message to my specific one? Also, on error it only returns errors, hwo do i make rails also return "old" model which faild so user dont have to hit face agains the wall and type all the text again from scratch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Attribute Names**

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371423/exclude-attribute-name-prepending-in-error-message) & [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792045/errors-full-messages-attribute-name-appears-twice), the core problem you have is your `attribute` name is prepending the error message. The way to fix this is to some how  remove the `attribute` name from the error message:

> ```
> #config/locales/en.yml
> en:
>   errors:
>     format: "%{message}"
> ```
>
> The default is `%{attribute} %{message}`

--

We've done it this way before, although I don't think this works in Rails 4:

```
<%= @model.errors.full_messages.each do |attribute, message| %>
   <%= message %>
<% end %>
```